# Check if uploaded file is video or not based on it's input stream

Tags: c#, file-upload, mime-types, content-type

I have a web form application in C# and I have to check if file type is video or not based on it's input stream.

I've tried several ways, including below.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        try
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length <= 0)
                txt_response.Text = "Invalid file.";

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            if (fs.Length >= 256)
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
            else
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);

            System.UInt32 mimetype;
            FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
            System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
            string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);

            //mime of video file remains application/octet-stream

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

[DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(System.UInt32 pBC, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer, System.UInt32 cbSize, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed, System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags, out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut, System.UInt32 dwReserverd);
}
```

This above code works fine for most of the file types, but for videos it returns application/octate-stream, although video is mp4.

Isn't there any way we can check on that buffer and decide it's a video file or it's image file etc?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) -- [MimeGuesser](https://github.com/hey-red/Mime)

Comment: @Jimi thanks, any idea on how to get this from signatures or magic numbers from InputStream?

Comment: If you use the MimeGuesser tool, it has overloads to which you can pass either a byte array or a Stream object. If you do that yourself (with, e.g., a `Dictionary<MimeType, byte[]>`), it's the same thing you're doing now: instead of reading 256 bytes, read each `Value.Length` of the dictionary. Note that the `mp4` format (as other similar media) is a container, so it may *contain* different sub-formats, but maybe you're not interested in the sub-formats, just the container Type.

Comment: You can also take those 256 bytes (it's much more than it's required for any signature), then - assume a Value from the `Dictionary<MimeType, byte[]>` is `var mimeBytes = new byte[] { FF, D8, FF, E0 };` (base JPEG/JFIF) -  you can then compare the sequence as `var isEqual = streamBytes.Take(mimeBytes.Length).SequenceEqual(mimeBytes);`. Of course looping the KeyValuePairs or your Dictionary. If/When a value matches, take the Dictionary Key at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library? I use it to check whether the input file is MP4 in my application:

```
var fileType = FileTypeDetector.DetectFileType(fileStream);

IsVideoFileFormatValid = fileType == FileType.Mp4;
```

Have a look at [this page](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/File-Type-Detection) of their documentation.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the project in any way.